# Multiple boxplots based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, boxplot

I have a dataframe with two columns. The power column represents the power consumption of the system. And the component_status column divide the data in two, based when the component is OFF or ON. When the values are 153 is when the component is ON and when the values are 150 the component is OFF.

The result that I am looking for is to have a boxplot with three boxplots, using `sns.boxplot`. One is the power consumption with all the data, called "TOTAL". The other two, the power consumption based if the component was OFF or ON, called "COMPONENT = ON" "COMPONENT = OFF".

The data frame example is as follows:

```
power|component_status |
 0.5 |       150       | 
 1.5 |       150       | 
 2.5 |       150       |
 0.3 |       153       |
 0.5 |       153       | 
 1.5 |       153       | 
 2.5 |       150       |
 0.3 |       153       |
```

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first step is to build your data frame with the conditions. There are a few ways to go about this.

1. Let's start with an initial `df1` (dataframe #1) as you have given. Then, let's add a `condition` column to say "Total". You can use `print(df1)` to see what this looks like.
2. Then let's copy that dataframe into `df2`, and let's replace the `conditions` with the off/on criteria from the `component_status`.
3. Our final dataframe `df` is just a concatenation of `df1` and `df2`.
4. Now we have a dataframe `df` that is ready to go in Seaborn.

#### Imports and DataFrame

```py
# Set up
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

power = [0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 0.3, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 0.3]
component_status = [150, 150, 150, 153, 153, 153, 150, 153]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    data=zip(power, component_status), columns=["power", "component_status"]
)

# Step 1
df1["condition"] = "Total"
# print(df1)

# Step 2
df2 = df1.copy()

df2["condition"] = np.where(df2["component_status"] == 153, "On", "Off")

# If you have several criteria, it can be easier to use np.select
# ... or just use Pandas directly:
# df2.loc[(df2['component_status'] == 153), 'condition'] = 'On'
# df2.loc[(df2['component_status'] == 150), 'condition'] = 'Off'

### Step 3
df = pd.concat([df1,df2])
```

#### `df` view

```py
   power  component_status condition
0    0.5               150     Total
1    1.5               150     Total
2    2.5               150     Total
3    0.3               153     Total
4    0.5               153     Total
5    1.5               153     Total
6    2.5               150     Total
7    0.3               153     Total
0    0.5               150       Off
1    1.5               150       Off
2    2.5               150       Off
3    0.3               153        On
4    0.5               153        On
5    1.5               153        On
6    2.5               150       Off
7    0.3               153        On
```

#### Plotting

```
# Step 4
ax = sns.boxplot(data=df, x='condition', y='power')
```

[image]